# Some curves ignore the curve resolution, Active Spline field missing settings

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm experiencing a bizarre issue: Certain curves appear to offer options that other curves do not, specifically the ability to set the resolution of the active spine. I noticed this because one curve is smooth (follows the resolution setting) while the other is not (each curve point is a also a geometry vertex). Both curves are paths: I checked everywhere and couldn't find anything that should be different between them. Attached is a simple blend file with the two curves.

https://pasteall.org/blend/36b78757e2cd4157be261f42743f4d32

When selecting the first curve, you get this set of settings under the Active Spline section which contains all options as desired:

[image]

But when selecting the second curve, the section only offers two of those options, the rest are inexplicably gone!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the help of StrayBillie from the BlenderArtists forum: I fixed my curve by selecting it then pressing F3 and looking for Curve - Set Spline Type - NURBS. I wasn't aware of the different spline types till now.